# Having problem importing data from a google sheets workbook to a master workbook, code cant find first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cant make the range that i selected go to the first empty row in column A in sheet 1.

Im new to Google-App-Script, and have never done anything in Java before, just read some tutorials.
Im trying to automate some lab machines so that the data they return go to a master workbook.

```
function macro (){
var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('E16:F');
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range)
var copy = s1.getRange('E16:F36').getValues();
var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXinBTHIhEf78AHe2zpSz6ugi1qgmd5WwqSg81IFrfk/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=102308466606203090938')
var column = s2.getRange('A:A');
var values = column.getValues();
var ct = 0;
while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) 
ct++;
var lastCell = s2.getRange('E16:F36');
var paste = s2.getRange('ct:B').setValues(copy);
}
```

I expect the code to set the data from the source workbook to be placed in the first empty row on the master workbook in sheet 1.

Comment: Google Apps Script is based on [tag:javascript] not on [tag:java]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `getLastRow()` method of spreadsheet class

```
  var lastRow = s2.getLastRow(); 
  var newStartRow = lastRow +1;
```

and then add 1 to it to define first row to paste your data to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

> Appends a row to the spreadsheet. This operation is atomic; it prevents issues where a user asks for the last row, and then writes to that row, and an intervening mutation occurs between getting the last row and writing to it.